# magento url rewrite

Tags: seo, magento, url-rewriting

Can someone tell me how the rewrite cathomepagina?catid=3

to

horloges-3.html in magento...

cos i keep getting page not find after the 301 redirect

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the web admin interface, navigate to `Catalog > URL Rewrite Management`.  You can add a custom rewrite using that interface.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,i did that...when i redirect shop to julewielshuizen.html it works but if i do cathomepage?cat_id=3 to horloges-3.html it wont work maybe this has something to do with the parameter?

Comment: hmm, you could try writing a one-off entry in your .htaccess file using the standard apache mod_rewrite syntax (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  Alternatively, check that horloges-3.html isn't being used by another product in the catalog?  

Finally, you could put your server into debug and set a breakpoint in `Core/Model/Mysql4/Url/Rewrite.php` to trace what's actually happening...

Comment: txs for your answer Jonathan i will try look in to it later

Comment: oke i got some things running here seems to be that he only will redirect things which are in the cms...so where should i put me redirects in here:############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: I'd suggest you add your new commands immediately above the first line that you pasted in.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to make sure your Magento cache files are cleared!